# preg_match против SQL-инъекции

Tags: php, sql

Подскажите, как будет выглядеть паттерн с учетом всевозможных подборов для SQL-инъекции. Проверка через `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

Или уже будет достаточно только того, что все ссылки формируются через `RewriteRule` c условием `[a-z0-9-_/]+` и простенький паттерн фильтрации `preg_match('/[^-a-z0-9_\/]/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])`?

З.Ы. Вопрос к экспертам!

Comment: Если что - данные могут идти через POST... Их вы разом не отфильтруете...

Comment: Если что - вопрос стоял конкретно о отправке данных через адресную строку!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В принципе RewriteRule совместно с /^[a-z0-9-_]/ достаточно, просто постарайтесь без \w - тут могут быть подводные камни

А лучше работать с SQL-ем через [PDO](https://www.php.net/pdo). Плейсхолдеры из того что я знаю лучшая вещь от SQL-инекций

Comment: Лучшая вещь от SQL инъекций это SQL процедуры :)

Но это, конечно, довольно таки непривычно в разработке, зато потом, вместо запросов, всяких там real_escape_string и тому подобной жути будет просто что-то типа 

     mysql_query("CALL addNewUser($login, $password)");

что довольно таки интересно смотрится и в плане разработки отделяет SQL от модели( при использовании MVC парадигмы в разработке ).

Хотя конечно я согласен - PDO отличная вещь и глупо ей не пользоваться...